# Konva JS - How add Shapes custom with input value

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs, konva

I'm trying to add a custom element using buttons, when I add a new element and change the radius of the input, it changes the radius of all the circles in the square. I don't know what to do, I've already seen and revised my code and I couldn't find a solution.

I tried to find in the documentation what may be happening, I imagine the reason is that Scene func updates all objects. The big point is that if I add a circle when I create the layer it does not update when I add it via the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.0.1/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Custom Shape Demo</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
    x <input type="number" name="x" id="x">
y <input type="number" name="y" id="y">
raio <input type="number" name="raio" id="raio">
<button onclick="addCircle()">addQuad</button>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
    
    function addCircle(){
        x1 = document.getElementById('x').value
    y1 = document.getElementById('y').value 
    raio2 = document.getElementById('raio').value
    
     var triangle = new Konva.Shape({
        sceneFunc: function (context, shape) {
          context.beginPath();
            context.arc(y1, x1, raio2, 2 * Math.PI, 0);
          context.closePath();

          // (!) Konva specific method, it is very important
          context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
        },
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true,
      });

      // add the triangle shape to the layer
      layer.add(triangle);
    
    layer.draw();
    
    }
      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();

      /*
       * create a triangle shape by defining a
       * drawing function which draws a triangle
       */
     
      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was cleaning your code and the error disappeared ...
Not exactly sure what was wrong, but it works, see my code below

Here are some things I found sticky in your code:

- The arc you had `context.arc(y1, x1, raio2` I think it should be x then y
- I split the function into two one that collects the elements another that draws
- The new function takes a few more parameters to control color and stroke width
- I'm also drawing a couple of circles to show it  working

```js
function addCircle() {
  x = document.getElementById('x').value
  y = document.getElementById('y').value
  r = document.getElementById('raio').value
  circle(x, y, r, '#00D2FF', 4)
}

function circle(x, y, r, fillColor, strokeWidth) {
  layer.add(new Konva.Shape({
    sceneFunc: function(context, shape) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, r, 2 * Math.PI, 0);
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
    },
    fill: fillColor,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
    draggable: true,
  }));
  layer.draw();
}

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
circle(100, 100, 8, "red", 2)
circle(200, 90, 6, "blue", 1)
```

```css
input {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.0.1/konva.min.js"></script>

x <input type="number" name="x" id="x" value="20"> 
y <input type="number" name="y" id="y" value="20"> 
raio <input type="number" name="raio" id="raio" value="10">
<button onclick="addCircle()">addQuad</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```